# Sending Tab and Enter Keys with WebDriverJS

Tags: coffeescript, webdriver, webdriver-io

This seems kinda basic but it has been giving me nothing but trouble.  I have a  UL LI list that I have styled as tabs.  When I test in  browser when I click and give focus to the second tab then click the TAB key on the keyboard and enter it gives focus to the 3rd tab and selects it.

I am trying to simulate this using WebDriverJS  with the following coffeescript code in my test using  chai, onecolor, etc.  The part is that giving me the problem is with I can get all normal characters to go fine but none of the special characters seems to work in my sauce labs selenium using this documentation [JSON WIRE PROTOCOL](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/JsonWireProtocol#/session/%3asessionId/element/%3aid/value).  The implementation I am using is from http://webdriver.io/ and the tests are running in https://saucelabs.com/.

```
  it 'tab key and enter works', (done) ->
    @timeout 10000
    @driver.waitFor '.tab.active', 10000, =>
      @driver.addValue '.tab:nth-child(2)', ['U+E004', 'U+E007'], (err) =>
        @driver.getElementCssProperty 'css selector', '.tab:nth-child(3)', 'background-color', (err, backgroundColor) =>
          @driver.getElementCssProperty 'css selector', '.tab:nth-child(3)', 'color', (err, color) =>
            onecolor('#ffffff').cssa().should.equal backgroundColor
            onecolor('#000000').cssa().should.equal color
            done()
```

Comment: It looks like you are using this [WebDriverJS](https://github.com/camme/webdriverjs), which is not the [WebDriverJS](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/WebDriverJs) provided by the Selenium project. (I'm saying this because I can't find an `addValue` method in the WebDriverJs provided by the Selenium project.) Can you please clarify this?

Comment: Correct I am using http://webdriver.io/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use all kinds of unicode characters. To do so you need to set the name of the key as input value (case sensitive). For example:

```
client.addValue('.tab:nth-child(2)',['Tab','Enter']) // press TAB + ENTER
```

or

```
client.addValue('.tab:nth-child(2)',['Meta','c']) // copy text into clipboard
```

If you don't want to link the keypress action to any input field you can use the `keys` protocol command to do this action:

```
client.keys(['Meta','c'])
```

Comment: I tried Tab and Enter first but the documentation said it works better by sending the U+E004 & U+E007 etc.  What I found that it doesn't respect addValue unless it is an input field.  Webdriver.io doesn't seem to have a way just to pass keyboard presses it expected it to be linked to a field.

Comment: It doesn't have to! You can also do keypress actions without linking it to a field by using the `keys` protocol command: `client.keys(['Meta','c'], function(err,res){...})`. I know this is nowhere documented but it will be within v2.0.0.

Comment: Yeah for not documented functionality.